# Ubuntu 15.1 PGP not working

Tags: password, encryption, keys, pgp

I am trying to create a PGP key on my ubuntu version 15.1. I find passwords and key and hit the "+" button to create a new PGP. I enter all the info, but after I submit my password no progress bar pops up for the actual encryption progress. My cursor gets large and small while I move it around the screen but it never encrypts my key. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're not using GPG? A "real" pgp doesn't appear to be in the standard repos (from a name search), though there is a `pgpgpg` "Wrapper for using GnuPG in programs designed for PGP"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Passwords & Keys in U14, click the +, select PGP, ok, then wait a few minutes, and click on PGP and your key pair should appear. I thought it was strange too with no status to let you know something's happening.

Comment: thanks, this is correct. I'm new to ubuntu, but I'll get there eventually